# Cluster CDH installation stuck at download

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am trying to set up a cluster on 3 nodes on a Cloud Server with Cloudera Manager. But at Cluster installation step, it gets stuck at 64%. Please guide me on how to go forward with it and where to see logs of the same.

Following is the image of the installation screen

[image: CloudEra Cluster Installation]

Comment: There's /var/log on the file system that shows you error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cloud companies have policies in which they if lots of data requests are coming, they remove the IP from public hostings for sometime. This is done to prevent DDoS attacks.
A solution can be to ask them to raise the data transfer limit.